# Run method from extends Activity extends Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, extends, runnable

I'm trying to call a method from inside a Runnable that is running. It waits for a string to be entered and when it is then depending on the string (the strings act as commands) it calls a method and is supposed to run whats inside it.

```
public class App extends Activity implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

         try {
             ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);
             while (true) {          
                 Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                 try {

                      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                      String str = in.readLine();
                      if(str.equals("test")) {
                          //method call here
                      }

                 } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.d("App", e.getMessage());

                 } finally {
                            client.close();
                        Log.d("App", "Done.");
                    }
             }       
         } catch (Exception e) {
             Log.d("App", e.getMessage());
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `Handler` object. Each `Handler` instance is associated with a thread, and depending on what thread you want to associate/handle the messages on, you should create the `Handler` within its context. Then you can push the messages onto the `Message` queue of the thread creating the `Handler`. As the string comes in you can use something like this:

```
public Handler handler_use = new Handler(){

    // @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       //Do something with the message
    }
}
```

And inside the try block:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    String str = in.readLine();
    if(str.equals("test")) {
        //Construct the message Msg - based on the string
        handler_use.sendMessage(Msg);
    }
}
```